# Can I trigger "(Re)Import Assets" from plugin code in Godot?

Tags: godot, godot4, godot3

I am writing a plugin for custom import assets from OS. I pick assets on disk and copy them to Godot project structure. Then I need to trigger generating .import file for the imported images, but I cannot see any way to do it from code.

I know there is a way of writing own import plugin and import assets from Godot IDE but I prefer to do the task by standalone separated plugin.

Found EditorImportPlugin class but it does not do what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are methods in the [EditorFileSystem](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_editorfilesystem.html) class for managing file imports. You can use [update_file](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_editorfilesystem.html#class-editorfilesystem-method-update-file), [reimport_files](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_editorfilesystem.html#class-editorfilesystem-method-reimport-files), or [scan](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_editorfilesystem.html#class-editorfilesystem-method-scan). (snake_case names are GDScript, the C# equivalents are UpdateFile, ReimportFiles, and Scan)

The documentation for reimport_files notes:

> Reimports a set of files. Call this if these files or their .import
> files were directly edited by script or an external program.
>
> If the file type changed or the file was newly created, use
> update_file or scan.

A small example of how to get and use the EditorFileSystem instance from an EditorScript (C#):

```
var filesystem = GetEditorInterface().GetResourceFilesystem();
filesystem.Scan()
```

Comment: Thank you! You saved my life =)